# Is $2$ always a $p^{\rm th}$-power nonresidue modulo $2^p-1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

That is, is following inequality holds while $p \in \mathbb{P}$?
$$ x^p \neq 2 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 2^p-1) $$
Certainly $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Suppose there is a prime $q|2^p−1$ so that $q\nequiv 1\pmod{p^2}$ (note that any $q|2^p−1$ is $1\pmod{p}$). Then $x^p\equiv 2\pmod{2^p−1}$ implies $x^p\equiv 2\pmod{q}$ and so $1\equiv 2^{\frac{q−1}{p}}\pmod{q}$. But since $2^p\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ this gives a contradiction. In particular your statement is true whenever $p$ is not a Wieferich prime. I'm not sure about the general case.